# Have you encountered the similar problem like loss jitter during training?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard, loss, bert-language-model

**Background:** It's about loss jittering which generates at the beginning stage of every training epoch. When the dataloader loads the first batch data to feed into the network, the loss value always rises suddenly, then returns to normal from the second batch and continues to decline. The curve is so strange. I need your help!

[image]

```py
    for epoch in range(begin_epoch, end_epoch):
        print('PROGRESS: %.2f%%' % (100.0 * epoch / end_epoch))

        # set epoch as random seed of sampler while distributed training
        if train_sampler is not None and hasattr(train_sampler, 'set_epoch'):
            train_sampler.set_epoch(epoch)

        # reset metrics
        metrics.reset()

        # set net to train mode
        net.train()

        # clear the paramter gradients
        # optimizer.zero_grad()

        # init end time
        end_time = time.time()

        if isinstance(lr_scheduler, torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau):
            name, value = validation_monitor.metrics.get()
            val = value[name.index(validation_monitor.host_metric_name)]
            lr_scheduler.step(val, epoch)

        # training
        train_loader_iter = iter(train_loader)
        for nbatch in range(total_size):
            try:
                batch = next(train_loader_iter)
            except StopIteration:
                print('reset loader .. ')
                train_loader_iter = iter(train_loader)
                batch = next(train_loader_iter)
            global_steps = total_size * epoch + nbatch

            os.environ['global_steps'] = str(global_steps)

            # record time
            data_in_time = time.time() - end_time

            # transfer data to GPU
            data_transfer_time = time.time()
            batch = to_cuda(batch)
            data_transfer_time = time.time() - data_transfer_time

            # forward
            forward_time = time.time()
            outputs, loss = net(*batch)
            loss = loss.mean()
            if gradient_accumulate_steps > 1:
                loss = loss / gradient_accumulate_steps
            forward_time = time.time() - forward_time

            # backward
            backward_time = time.time()
            if fp16:
                with amp.scale_loss(loss, optimizer) as scaled_loss:
                    scaled_loss.backward()
            else:
                loss.backward()
            backward_time = time.time() - backward_time

            optimizer_time = time.time()
            if (global_steps + 1) % gradient_accumulate_steps == 0:

                # clip gradient
                if clip_grad_norm > 0:
                    if fp16:
                        total_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(amp.master_params(optimizer),
                                                                    clip_grad_norm)
                    else:
                        total_norm = torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(),
                                                                    clip_grad_norm)
                    if writer is not None:
                        writer.add_scalar(tag='grad-para/Total-Norm',
                                        scalar_value=float(total_norm),
                                        global_step=global_steps)

                optimizer.step()
                
                # step LR scheduler
                if lr_scheduler is not None and not isinstance(lr_scheduler,
                                                            torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau):
                    lr_scheduler.step()

                # clear the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()
            optimizer_time = time.time() - optimizer_time

            # update metric
            metric_time = time.time()
            metrics.update(outputs)
            if writer is not None and nbatch % 50 == 0:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    for group_i, param_group in enumerate(optimizer.param_groups):
                        writer.add_scalar(tag='Initial-LR/Group_{}'.format(group_i),
                                        scalar_value=param_group['initial_lr'],
                                        global_step=global_steps)
                        writer.add_scalar(tag='LR/Group_{}'.format(group_i),
                                        scalar_value=param_group['lr'],
                                        global_step=global_steps)
                    writer.add_scalar(tag='Train-Loss',
                                    scalar_value=float(loss.item()),
                                    global_step=global_steps)
                    name, value = metrics.get()
                    for n, v in zip(name, value):
                        if 'Logits' in n:
                            writer.add_scalar(tag='Train-Logits/' + n,
                                            scalar_value=v,
                                            global_step=global_steps)
                        else:
                            writer.add_scalar(tag='Train-' + n,
                                            scalar_value=v,
                                            global_step=global_steps)
                    for k, v in outputs.items():
                        if 'score' in k:
                            writer.add_histogram(tag=k,
                                                 values=v,
                                                 global_step=global_steps)

            metric_time = time.time() - metric_time
```

Comment: try shuffling your data at the beginning of each epoch

Comment: oh, I‘m using IterableDataset. The object doesn't support shuffle ops yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You have a batch in your dataset that have high loss, that's it.

It is not that common that people store metrics for every batch, usually it is the average over epoch (or average over multiple batch steps) that is stored. You won't see such spikes if you will store averages.

You also could reduce these spikes by shuffling your data so that the problematic batch is spread out across the epoch. In general it is a good practice to do so at the beginning of each epoch.

Comment: Really really thank your answer!! Could I ask you a question? Why the problematic always appears in the first batch. I set 8 works and they are in the same situation appearing spikes at the first batch loader of each epoch, and then it will be normal. Shouldn't the problematic batch be randomly distributed in the dataset? Thanks again!

Comment: How do you know that this is the first batch? I don't think that I could say that just by examining the plot. But I can't tell for certain without looking at your data. But in general it is normal to have spikes.

Comment: I complete agree with what you said! I also check the log file and verify that only the first batch causing the spikes. Maybe only the first batch is problematic? even in all of 8 workers? It feels a little kind of coincidence...